SQL - Modifiy table field based on another table field
I have a SQL table named Rights with the following fields: rightId, RightName, ParentRightId, RightIsActive.
The RightName field contains the name of each right, including its parent rights separated by underscores.
For example, if right 3 is a child of right 2, and right 2 is a child of right 1, then the name of right 3 would be '1_2_3'.
I want the ParentRightId field to hold the value of the parent's rightId based on its name. How can I achieve this ?
I already tried this code and didn't managed to make it work :
UPDATE Rights AS r1
JOIN Rights AS r2 ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(r1.RightName, '_', -1) = SUBSTRING_INDEX(r2.RightName, '_', 1)
SET r1.ParentRightId = r2.rightId;

Here is the table create query :
CREATE TABLE `Rights` (
  `rightId` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `RightName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `RightLibelle` text,
  `ParentRightId` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `RightIsActive` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`rightId`),
  KEY `ParentRightId` (`ParentRightId`),
  CONSTRAINT `Rights_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ParentRightId`) REFERENCES `Rights` (`rightId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=256 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

And a snippet of code to create example data :
INSERT INTO `Rights` VALUES 
 (1,'CAROUSEL MENU',NULL,NULL,1)
,(2,'CAROUSEL MENU_SALES',NULL,NULL,1)
,(3,'CAROUSEL MENU_SALES_CONFIGURATOR',NULL,NULL,1)
;

Thanks !

Please provide tables DDL and some sample data

Sorry, I just updated it ! Feel free to ask clarifications if it's unclear

Given the sample what do you expect the result to be?

The sample data you gave does not match the rule you want a solution for "... then the name of right 3 would be '1_2_3'". In the examples you gave there is an extra word before the "parents". Unless space is a valid character for naming (which was not explicitly added to the question). When working with strings every detail matters. Also, RightName is not unique and it should be given this rule.
Depending on your mysql version it can be done either with a function/procedure (which there are tons of answers for) or with recursive CTE. So please specify the version you are using.

I should have specified that space does count as a character for the names. The only character that does not count is the underscore, used to make the distinction between 2 names

As we can see in your data example, we can self join table Rights where RightName of parent right is substring of RightName of child right.
Then take the longest of them.
See example
UPDATE Rights AS trg
JOIN ( 
  select t1.rightId, t2.rightId parentId
    ,row_number()over(partition by t1.rightId order by length(t2.RightName) desc)rn
  from Rights t1
  left join Rights t2 on t1.rightId<>t2.rightId 
    and substring(t1.RightName,1,length(t2.RightName))=t2.RightName
)src on src.rightId=trg.rightId
  SET trg.ParentRightId = src.parentId
where rn=1;

Result is



rightId
RightName
RightLibelle
ParentRightId
RightIsActive




1
CAROUSEL MENU
null
null
1


2
CAROUSEL MENU_SALES
null
1
1


3
CAROUSEL MENU_SALES_CONFIGURATOR
null
2
1



Source for UPDATE



rightId
RightName
ParentRightId
RightIsActive
parentId
RightName
rn




1
CAROUSEL MENU
null
1
null
null
1


2
CAROUSEL MENU_SALES
null
1
1
CAROUSEL MENU
1


3
CAROUSEL MENU_SALES_CONFIGURATOR
null
1
2
CAROUSEL MENU_SALES
1


3
CAROUSEL MENU_SALES_CONFIGURATOR
null
1
1
CAROUSEL MENU
2



Demo

If I understand your question, I think you really want the following SQL:
UPDATE Rights AS r1
JOIN Rights AS r2 ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(r1.RightName, '_', 2) = SUBSTRING_INDEX(r2.RightName, '_', 1)
SET r1.ParentRightId = r2.rightId;

If each RightName contains 3 levels (grandparent_parent_child), then the string from '1_2_3' that will be in its parent RightName will be '1_2'. For example, the parent RightName could be '9_1_2'. So from the record with RightName '1_2_3' you need to compare the first three characters to the last three characters of the RightName of its parent. The -1 value in your first SUBSTRING_INDEX() call will give you only '3'.
From https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index
Regarding the third parameter of this function, "If count is positive, everything to the left of the final delimiter is returned. If count is negative, everything to the right of the final delimiter is returned."

I understand what you tried to do but the data can have more parents than 2. The other comment solved my problem, thanks for taking the time to answer it ! :)
